# How to restrict query to require at least five correct characters in a PHP search form

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, database

I'm working on creating a search form where clients will be able to enter their vin number to a vehicle and the other related columns in that row will be displayed. I've gotten this process working to some extent by using a 'where like' operator in my select statement, however, I want clients to have to enter at least five correct digits before any rows are returned.

In my code's current state, just entering a single digit will return all rows with that digit. Additionally, entering nothing and searching will result in all rows being displayed.

Here is what my select statement currently looks like:

```
$query = "SELECT Record, `EMAIL 2`, DATEi, DATEf, PROJECT, `SAMPLE DESCRIPTION`, `FLD5_(As/VIN)` FROM `tbl_2018a` WHERE CONCAT (`EMAIL 2`, `PROJECT`, `SAMPLE DESCRIPTION`, `FLD5_(As/VIN)`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
```

valueToSearch in this case is the variable controlled by the client while preforming the search.

Is there a way to restrict the amount of characters the client must enter correctly before the results are displayed through either PHP or by modifying the select statement?

Comment: Have you tried something like `if(strlen($valueToSearch) < 5)) { return "More than 5 characters, please?";}`?  You may want something more graphically-oriented, in which case you also need JS.

Comment: The easiest way would be to not send the request to the server until 5 characters were entered in the form field. Just validate on the server that the variable is at least 5 characters long before running the query.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 solutions Client-side validation and Server-side validation :

Both need to be implemented by end of the day else you can't enforce the proper validation. And you can't just rely on client-side validation.

1. Client-side handling

   **It's better to put the client side validation first. Else you're hitting the server with unnecessary calls which can, in turn, affect your optimizations and performance in the long run, if not immediately.**

If you're using the jQuery than on KEYUP while typing in the search bar you can check the number of characters enter in the search box in the length is more than or equal to 5 characters then only allowed to go for the ajax request.

/* Assuming that you may have the following kind of **HTML** */

```
<input type="text" name="filter" id="filter">
<span id="filter-error"></span> <!-- To show the filter error option, not a mandatory but useful to know the user whats causing the problem -->
```

For example to implement in **jQuery**

```
$('#filter').on('keyup', function(){
    //
    var searchData = $(this).val();
    if(searchData == undefined || searchData.length < 5){
        $('#filter-error').html("Please enter atleast 5 characters.");
        return false;
    }

    /* Else the normal jQuery call what you want to handle her for sending the ajax request */
    $.ajax({
        /* Implementation */
    });
});
```

2. Implementing on Serverside ie **PHP**

Once the form is submitted you need to check for the following validation.

> Note: I am not demonstrating anything against a security vulnerability

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ /* Check if its a post method and not get method */
    $filter = trim($_POST['filter']); /* making sure to trim the spaces just to make sure user doesnt post white spaces */
    (strlen($filter)) ? (return 'Please enter atlease 5 characters') : '';

    /* Even you can check for some more validations like whether its having only AlphaNumeric only or not or anything which you require */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. I was able to find a solution by modifying my html from to restrict the amount of minimum characters entered by the client.

```
<form action="php_html_table_data_filter.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" required minlength="5" maxlength="30" placeholder="Search"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find Project"><br><br>
```

The 'required minlength' and 'required maxlength' functions were able to solve my problem and restrict client-side how many characters the user must eneter before the data is returned to the server.